# Is it possible to use an S3 bucket policy to set an Expires header 1 week in the future for all jpg, gif and png files?

Tags: amazon-s3

Is it possible to use an S3 bucket policy to set an Expires header (and/or max-age?) 1 week in the future for all jpg, gif and png files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't set expires headers with the Bucket Policies. Although there is a Condition statement in the policy that let's you specify the date,  it serves to specify when the policy is effective rather than for content expiration

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {},
      "Condition": {
        "DateLessThan": {
          "aws:CurrentTime": "2011-09-01T07:00:32Z"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```